# EJBCA install to JBoss via Chef not working

Tags: jboss, chef-infra, ejbca

in my chef recipe, i install ejbca via

```
# install ejbca
script "install ejbca->jboss" do
    interpreter "bash"
    user "#{node[:ejbca][:user]}"
    code <<-EOF
        cd #{node[:ejbca][:dir]}
        ant install
    EOF
end
```

and returns an error

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ejbca not bound

but when i `ant install` inside vagrant ssh, it is successfully completed. Already checked on user permissions and group.

Comment: Not sure if that helps, but using the execute resource, this can look a bit cleaner (setting cwd to the directory)

Comment: already tried. still the same.

Comment: same issue, it has to do with hostname and /etc/hosts